# SQL Server 2016 MDS - installation prerequisites

Tags: sql-server, mds

I'd like to try SQL Server 2016 MDS, but I could not find any clear list of installation prerequisites.

1. Which Windows server version - can it be less than 2012?
2. SQL Server version - can it be SQL Server 2012?

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

HAve you seen these links?

[Install Master Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633752.aspx)

[Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)

[Database Requirements (Master Data Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633767.aspx)